# fscanf and dynamic array allocation

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, scanf

I am trying to read something from a txt file using `fscanf`. I am only reading a word in each time. And I am counting how many words I've collected. So that I can create a dynamic array with the count of words. Each element of array will contain a word. But I don't know how. Here is my code

```
pFile = fopen(inFile, "r");
char *chr;
if(pFile != NULL) // Process if the file is not empty
{
    while(!feof(pFile))
    {
        chr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
        num++;
        fscanf(pFile, "%s", chr);
    }
    printf("%s",chr);

}
```

And my example of the txt file is like that: hello world

Comment: Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: also, usage instruction related to [`feof()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2173917)

Comment: I want to get a word each time thats why i use %s

Comment: @SouravGhosh we really need a tag that automatically expands to "do not cast the result of malloc" with the suitable link :p

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` is a compile time operator (with the exception of variable length array). In particular, `sizeof(char*)` is the size of a pointer to `char`, which is normally 4 in 32-bit machines, or 8 in 64-bit machines. So the size is not as dynamic as you thought.

An alternative is to `malloc` a small array first, use `fgets` to get the line, if the size is too small (you can check if a `\n` is got), `realloc` to a bigger size. Use `sscanf` to get the data from the line.

Also, you never free the memory dynamically allocated, so there's memory leak.

Comment: Thank you I used free afterwards I know but im not about that one. I want to create an array withthe amount of read words..